# Is it possible to get information from a terminal into a flutter app? If yes, please share an example

Tags: flutter, dart, elasticsearch, terminal

I'm writing a flutter app that needs to set up elasticsearch on first run. To do this, I need to run some commands in the terminal, I know how to do it, but I also need information from the terminal for a complete setup. How to get information from terminal to my flutter app, can i assign the value of one of the terminal strings to some variable in flutter?

I not found a some issues about getting info from terminal to app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--dart-define` from the terminal while running your app or while building your application.

for example

```dart
flutter run --dart-define=BASE_URL=https://flutter.dev
```

Here `BASE_URL` is a key and you can pass value to it, you can name it as per your need.

And, You can access this in your `Flutter` app like below:

```dart
const String.fromEnvironment('BASE_URL')
```

You can check out this video as well for the same: [Passing values from the command line to Flutter app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1Q1P6z3X1A)

> `const` is required while accessing that value you pass using `dart-define` and the key name is case sensitive.